# Cross platoform compatibility of ipywidgets

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I tried looking up `ipywidgets` [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io) to find out if this library is cross platform compatible but in vain. I did not get any satisfactory or clear picture to my query. Can someone who has used this library throw light on the same?

By **cross-platform compatibility**, I mean the GUI should look and funtion identically on all major operating system (MacOS, Windows, Linux). I consider `Tkinter` a **non-cross platform compatible** library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes.

Ipywidgets pretty much just connect python to sliders and other controls that are created using html+js+css which is then rendered by the browser. Thus they will appear the same across OSes up to browsers being different between OSs. works in jupyter notebooks as well as other jupyter-like environments such as colab or [voila](https://voila.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html).